# Convert to text but keep dom layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm fetching the DOM HTML with `$(selector).html();` and converting it into text with this operation `$(selector).empty().text($(selector).html());`.

My problem is that `text();` converts the html into pure text without any formatting, is it possible to format the text into how it looks like in the dom?

I am inserting everything into a pre element so doing html() making it think it should handle it like any other html tags.

Like this:

[image]

(without the arrow-hide function)

Comment: Can you post the code for what you're doing?

Comment: The question is not understood please rephrase the 2nd part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to keep the DOM from the `$(selector).html()`, then you could just `.html` instead of `.text`:

```
$(selector).empty().html($(selector).html());
```

If you only wish to keep certain tags, then you can use this replace code ([from here](http://www.jquery4u.com/snippets/jquery-strip-html-tags-div/)) to strip all tags except the ones within the replace method:

```
rawHTML = $(selector).html().replace(/<\/?[br|li|ol|ul]+\/?>/igm,'');
$(selector).empty().html(rawHTML);
```

Comment: I am inserting everything into a pre element so a HTML tag will be interpreted as HTML code thus making the html() function not working.

Comment: In that case, try a plugin like [vkBeautify](http://www.eslinstructor.net/vkbeautify/) to format (pretty print) your html; the xml formatter should work for you in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to the text to keep the formatting of the html you can try the following

```
x = $(selector).html();
$(selector).text(x);
```

This would result in having the html tags as displayed.

e.g. the following line will dump the body's html to the body to be viewed with tags.

```
$("body").text($("body").html())
```